# How to service multiple resources in one process (SimPy simulation)?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I have a problem with simulating simple work conserving scheduler in SimPy. I want this scheduler to have 2 queues to work as simple round robin which services packet from queue number 1 and then services packet from queue number 2. If one of the queues is empty it goes to service packets from other queue (work conserving). Packets that were already serviced are sent to 1 common output.

I've already written a code based on this code (https://www.grotto-networking.com/DiscreteEventPython.html) to create such solution but it doesn't work as i wanted. Packets which are sent to queue number 1 are being serviced but packets in queue number 2 aren't. I think the problem might be with having multiple resources for 1 process and i don't know how to
resolve this problem.

```
class RoundRobinQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, env, rate, qlimit=None, limit_bytes=True):
        self.store = simpy.Store(env)
        self.store2 = simpy.Store(env)
        self.rate = rate
        self.env = env
        self.out = None
        self.packets_rec = 0
        self.packets_drop = 0
        self.qlimit = qlimit
        self.limit_bytes = limit_bytes
        self.byte_size = 0  # Current size of the queue in bytes
        self.busy = 0  # Used to track if a packet is currently being sent
        self.action = env.process(self.run())  # starts the run() method as a SimPy process
        self.trigger = 1

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if (self.trigger == 0 and len(self.store.items)>=0):
                self.trigger = 1
                msg = (yield self.store.get())
                self.byte_size -= msg.size
                self.busy = 1
                yield self.env.timeout(msg.size * 8.0 / self.rate)
                self.out.put(msg)
                self.busy = 0
            else:
                self.trigger = 1

            if (self.trigger == 1 and len(self.store2.items)>=0):
                self.trigger = 0
                msg2 = (yield self.store2.get())
                self.byte_size -= msg2.size
                self.busy = 1
                yield self.env.timeout(msg2.size * 8.0 / self.rate)
                self.out.put(msg2)
                self.busy = 0
            else:
                self.trigger = 0
```

Comment: does self.trigger get updated somewhere else?  The self.trgger code does not seem to be doing anything useful, unless its is being used as flag to other processes. How are the queues getting loaded? can you show all the code?

Comment: @Michael self. trigger is updated only in code above. Queues are being filled from other component named PacketGenerator (or PacketGenerator2) which use put or put2 method of RoundRobinQueue to store packets in correct queue (store or store2). Code is kind of long but you can see it on my github [link](https://github.com/melekuss/SimpySim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like when both queues are empty it falls into a infinite loop, added a check for that.  Also includes the fix where it only pulls from a queue if it is not empty

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        if len(self.store.items) + len(self.store2.items) ==0:
            # both queue are empty, wait a sec to avoid a infinate loop
            yield self.env.timeout(1)
        else:
            if len(self.store.items)>0:
                self.trigger = 1
                msg = (yield self.store.get())
                self.byte_size -= msg.size
                self.busy = 1
                yield self.env.timeout(msg.size * 8.0 / self.rate)
                self.out.put(msg)
                self.busy = 0
            else:
                self.trigger = 1

            if len(self.store2.items)>0:
                self.trigger = 0
                msg2 = (yield self.store2.get())
                self.byte_size -= msg2.size
                self.busy = 1
                yield self.env.timeout(msg2.size * 8.0 / self.rate)
                self.out.put(msg2)
                self.busy = 0
            else:
                self.trigger = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

i think

```
len(self.store.items)>=0
```

will always be true because a empty queue will have length of 0

to skip when the queue is empty I think

```
if (self.trigger == 0 and len(self.store.items)>=0):
```

should be

```
if len(self.store.items) > 0:
```

and

```
if (self.trigger == 1 and len(self.store2.items)>=0):
```

should be

```
if len(self.store2.items) > 0:
```

Comment: I've made those changes and the simulation doesn't progress (stays at 0). So it's stuck in while loop at time 0.

Comment: I'm not sure your problem is with this code

Comment: where do you call the run method?  somewhere in in main should there be a env.process(switch_port1.run())  before you call env.run(until=4000).  You may need to do this for all you objects that have a run method

Comment: or you can add the env.process as the last line of your __init__ to call the run method